# Positioning of listings

Tags: listings

Exists something like positioning of listings. I mean for instance something like [h] that is used by figure or tables. I would like to add it to

```
\mylisting[label=p]{p}{p.txt}
```

I have a

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  listing options={basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{4}

    \section{S}
       \mylisting[label=p]{p}{p.txt}
\end{document}
```

p.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
```

And the p.txt is too long to place on the same page like chapter and section, so it is on the second page. How to set it to begin below the section? Thank you

Comment: The `listings` package provides a `float` key which will make the listing float like `table` or `figure` does. Check the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: MWE not appropriate would be in most cases a false assumption.

Comment: I eddited my question

Comment: Call me stupid, but when I run the code with your file the box starts right below the section heading and breaks nicely to fit onto the following pages (MikTeX 2.9 fully updated). See also https://v1.overleaf.com/read/bsbmqmqqcnkd.

Comment: @moewe: Yes, for me too on my PC with TL 2018

Comment: There is also the `float` key for `tcolorbox`, i.e. `float=h` or `float=b` etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has solved your question by comments.